# p:fileUpload on iPad uploads Images upside down

Tags: ipad, primefaces, jsf-2

For my current project I have built an input mask with which I can upload pictures and display them. For this I use the FileUpload in multiple and advanced mode and the graphicImage component. The normal browser on my PC it works very well.

Now I have tried the same dialogue on my iPad. If I hold the iPad horizontal (home button on the right), it also works very well on the iPad.
If I hold the iPad the other way around (home button on the left), the images are displayed upside down (in the preview). When I now go to the dialoque via Browser (PC) the Image is shown updside down (graphicImage Component).

Is it possible that the image information to orientation the image is incorrectly read and processed? How can I correct or correct this error?

Comment: Did you try with a non-apple tablet? Or a mobile phone (apple and non-apple)

Comment: Currently not, maybe I can try it today.